# Laravel 5.3 Entrust - Class name must be a valid object or a string

Tags: php, laravel, entrust

I'm currently working on a `delete` function for my roles.

Every time when I try to delete:

```
Class name must be a valid object or a string
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this function into Role.php model

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Config::get('auth.providers.users.model'), 
            Config::get('entrust.role_user_table'), 
            Config::get('entrust.role_foreign_key'), 
            Config::get('entrust.user_foreign_key'));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Update the `config/auth.php` file with `'model' => App\Users::class` , because `vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/Entrust/Traits/EntrustRoleTrait.php` point to `Config::get('auth.model')` in the $this->belongsToMany() method.

Answer (score 0):

@Tiến Đạo says the best way to solve this problem. But If you want code simplicity....

```
use App\User;

class Role extends EntrustRole
{
   /**
   * Many-to-Many relations with the user model.
   *
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
   */
   public function users()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
   }
}
```